# How can I get from VB code the connectionStrings?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this in web.config and i need to use it from vb to pass it on a variable:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <add name="SQL1" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQL1").ConnectionString.ToString
```

You'll also need to add `Imports System.Configuration` is it's not set at the project level.

Comment: Not working this, tell me to change to ISys ..or AsyncOp..or oter bull that is also not working!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ConfigurationManager in System.Configuration

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cnnName").ConnectionString;

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL1"].ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL1"].ToString();
```